# Custom Script callback for infinitescroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

So there are many articles online about this, all the same thing and all do not work

What i want to do is run a JS function after infinite scroll has run.

When i try to run it i am getting s syntax error
       SyntaxError: missing : after property id, function(arrayOfNewElems) {

```
<script>
    if ( ! navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {
        var infinite_scroll = {
            loading: {
                img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif",
                msgText: "<?php _e( 'Loading the next set of products...', 'woothemes' ); ?>",
                finishedMsg: "<?php _e( 'All products loaded.', 'woothemes' ); ?>"
            }, function(arrayOfNewElems) {
                        $('img')equalHeights();
                    });,
            "nextSelector":".pagination a.next",
            "navSelector":".pagination",
            "itemSelector":"#main .product",
            "contentSelector":"#main ul.products"
        };
        jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
    }
    </script>
```

Does anyone know how on earth to just run the function equalHeights();

Comment: The problem is not with infinitescroll.js, your code has several syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are many syntax errors so I start easy.

```
   var infinite_scroll = {
        obj: {
            prop1 : val1,
        }, function() {}
    };
```

So there's one problem. You have to give the function a name. But when do you want to call it? When the loading finished? Than it has to look like that:

```
   var infinite_scroll = {
        loading: {
            finished : function() {}
        }
    };
```

In your function you have another syntax error:

```
$('img')equalHeights();
```

Should be:
    $('img').equalHeights();

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain that not those many articles online are wrong

Comment: Still getting same issue.
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 

finished : function() {$('.img-wrap')equalHeights();}